# Randomly generated group id for Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have an application that uses spring kafka to read messages. It is necessary that each instance of the application has a unique groupId, as well as reset it and get a new one on restart. The GroupId is randomly generated via `${random.uuid}`.

Is the solution to generate randomly id really correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, generating through `${random.uuid}` is correct.

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=${random.uuid}
```

There is also another choice if you want more control over the way the group id is generated. Use the `@KafkaListener` annotation with a Spring expression. From the [Spring Kafka reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation):

> You can configure most attributes on the annotation with SpEL by using #{…​} or property placeholders (${…​}). See the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) for more information.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "hi", groupId = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}")
```